# Regex to filter/match all characters except for specific char sequence

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I have this Jax-rs path:

```
@GET
@Path("{id: \\b(?!_ah)\\w+\b}") 
public Response get(...){...}
```

My goal is that this get method match all character sequence except those that starts with `_ah` like:

```
_ah\foo
_ah\foo\bar
```

However there is something wrong with the regex.

Comment: This answer might be of some use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/1276804

Comment: @zagyi thanks for the link. it still match the _ah\foo and _ah\foo\bar